what makes a step of a method claim considered as "performed" or "happened"
In a method claim:

performing at least one of:
in response to identifying a success A,  rewarding user A; and
in response to identifying a success B,  rewarding user B.

Question:

If neither success A nor B was identified, would any of the steps have been considered performed?
The steps do something on a condition of something else. If that something else never materialized, can it be argued that the "do something" bit is always satisfied? In other words, each of the action to be performed in each of two steps is to check a condition, rather than reward the user?


In the case that neither A or B is identified that method claim would not be infringed. If either sometimes happens then infringement does take place.
